# SDK options is not available for Kindle Fire in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, development-environment, kindle-fire

I have followed the procedure to set up the `development environment for Kindle Fire in Eclipse` from the  [Amazon Site](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/01-setting-up-your-development-environment). Though I added the add-on URL in **'Manage Add-On Site'** option correctly, still Android SDK Manager is not displaying the following options for downloading:

```
Android 4.2.2 (API 17)
SDK Platform
ARM EABI v7a System Image
Intel x86 Atom System Image
Kindle Fire HD 7″ (3rd Generation)
Kindle Fire HDX 7″ (3rd Generation)
Kindle Fire HDX 8.9″ (3rd Generation)
```

**Now I am able to see only :**

> [image]

Any clue ?? Suggestion ??.

Comment: Were you able to create the emulators for Kindle fire ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Kindle Fire HD 7″ (3rd Generation)
>
> Kindle Fire HDX 7″ (3rd Generation)
>
> Kindle Fire HDX 8.9″ (3rd Generation)

Those are the Kindle Fire emulators. They have been discontinued and no longer available to download.

> Amazon has discontinued support for the HD and HDX tablet emulators.
>
> You should follow the guidance at
>   https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/submitting-your-app/tech-docs/02-submitting-an-android-app
>   and
>   https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/submitting-your-app/tech-docs/03-pre-submission-assessment-guide
>   in order to optimize their Android apps for Kindle tablets.

https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9933&tstart=0