# Kindle Fire Devices not showing by eclipse sdk-manager

Tags: android, eclipse, kindle-fire

I have tried many times:
I am adding a addon in sdk-manager 
http://kindle-sdk.s3.amazonaws.com/addon.xml

But sdk-manager not showing any kindle-devices.
what i am missing.?
I have followed the tutorial:
https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/setup.html#SystemRequirements

I am using windows 8.1 os and latest bundled-eclipse from developer.android.com

Comment: Are you connecting a physical device or an emulator?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/22985395/2072811

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately amazon has dropped supporting the emulator so no device definitions are loaded.

Take a look here
[amazon developer forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=479)

Comment: Hey Thanks! I have seen that they dropped supporting the emulator,so now the only way is buying a personal testing device.?

Comment: not really. You can make your own device definition depending on the device you want to test your app to.
Search for the kindle fire device settings so you can setup the emulator like a kindle fire.

Check here http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Kindle_Fire_Android_Virtual_Device_(AVD)
under the title "Kindle Fire AVD Command-line Creation" it has a list with the previously supported AVDs. You can make your custom AVD with those settings and you would be really close to the actual Kindle Fire devices.

Comment: Thanks! can i run the samples on android phone.?

Comment: Of course you can run them on Android phone but you should check your layout with the Kindle Fire specs also if you plan on supporting them. So either you should find some tablets on same specs (hard and costly) or make your own avds on the emulator with the Kindle Fire specs depending on the devices you plan on supporting